# how can I inject DateTimeProvider / wrapper dependency in a component's class but not using the constructor?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, webforms, autofac

in a webforms application, let's say we have a class that has a method that does some job with the use of DateTime.Now, if I want to test this method I can inject a DateTimeWrapper using the constructor but in my scenario I don't want the IoC container to construct the class for me, instead I want to use it "new it" and have it testable and I think it makes no sense that each time we want to use this class, a dependency of the DateTimeWrapper "which returns the real DateTime.Now" should be injected!

**Note:** nothing is being injected in the WebForms page class.

```
public class EmailNotification
        {
            public IDateTimeWrapper DateTimeWrapper { get; set; }
            public void SetBody(string body)
            {
                ...
                Body = body + DateTimeWrapper.Now.ToString();
            }
        }
```

I tried to use Property injection using "Autofac" and the following works perfect:

```
builder.RegisterType<DateTimeWrapper>()
                .As<IDateTimeWrapper>();

builder.RegisterType<EmailNotification>().PropertiesAutowired();

// in this case, it works
var email = container.Resolve<EmailNotification>();
email.SetBody("hello world!");
```

But I need to use the component like this:

```
// somehow I want the DateTimeProvider "the real one" to be injected or used at this point
var email= new EmailNotification();
email.SetBody("hello world!");
// I'm getting a NullReferenceException at the last line because the dependency has been never injected
```

do you have an idea? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Something has to assign the desired dependency. Either you do it manually or delegate it to a container. No getting around that short of tightly coupling the class, which is a code smell.

Comment: Just do pure DI `var component = new Component() { DateTimeWrapper  = new DateTimeWrapper() };` or via constructor. But doing this in a method tightly couples the method to the class and its dependency

Comment: @Nkosi can i do it manually and still have the ability to unit test the method?

Comment: @Nkosi my friend, thank you for you comments but if component is an EmailNotification class, would you consider it logically fine to provide the DateTimeProvider using the constructor or the object initialization syntax each time we want to construct an instance?

Comment: because it's a Notification class which contains fields like From, To, Subject, Body, etc. but I made this example using terminology like component & service to have a simpler idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was simple "i think", I changed this:

```
public class EmailNotification
        {
            public IDateTimeWrapper DateTimeWrapper { get; set; }
            public void SetBody(string body)
            {
                ...
                Body = body + DateTimeWrapper.Now.ToString();
            }
        }
```

to the following:

```
public class EmailNotification
{
    private IDateTimeWrapper _dateTimeWrapper = new DateTimeWrapper();

    public IDateTimeWrapper DateTimeWrapper 
    {
        get
        {
            return _dateTimeWrapper;
        }
        set
        {
            _dateTimeWrapper = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(DateTimeWrapper));
        }
    }
    public void SetBody(string body)
    {
            ...
            Body = body + DateTimeWrapper.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

so I still have IDateTimeWrapper as a seam for unit testing and at the same time it gets initialized by default when constructing an instance of the EmailNotification class.